# JRadioButton and JCheckBox don't respond to right mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am trying to have JRadioButtons and JCheckBoxes that respond to right mouse clicks as well as left mouse clicks.  I am finding that they don't respond to right mouse clicks properly, but I can't figure out why.

```
private JRadioButton btn1 = new JRadioButton("1");
private JRadioButton btn2 = new JRadioButton("2");
private JRadioButton btn3 = new JRadioButton("3");
private JCheckBox btn4 = new JCheckBox("4");
private JCheckBox btn5 = new JCheckBox("5");

private ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

private void setupActionListeners() {
    btn1.addMouseListener(createMouseAdapter(btn1));
    btn2.addMouseListener(createMouseAdapter(btn2));
    btn3.addMouseListener(createMouseAdapter(btn3));
    btn4.addMouseListener(createMouseAdapter(btn4));
    btn5.addMouseListener(createMouseAdapter(btn5));
    group.add(btn1);
    group.add(btn2);
    group.add(btn3);
}

private MouseAdapter createMouseAdapter(final AbstractButton button) {
    return new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
           System.out.println("Button " + button.getText() + " selected = " + button.isSelected());
        }
    };
}
```

I used a program like above to see what the state of the buttons are when left or right mouse clicks are done.  It looks like in 3 of the cases, the right click values are wrong.

Could this be a bug in Java, or am I doing something wrong?

State results (sorry for the look, couldn't find a good way to add a table to this entry)

Button Type    **Mouse Button**    Button status at click time    **button.isSelected() in mouseClicked**

---

JRadioButton    **left**         not selected                        **TRUE**

JRadioButton    **right**            not selected                        **FALSE** <- wrong?

JRadioButton    **left**             selected                            **TRUE**

JRadioButton    **right**            selected                            **TRUE**

JCheckBox       **left**             not selected                        **TRUE**

JCheckBox       **right**            not selected                        **FALSE** <- wrong?

JCheckBox       **left**             selected                            **FALSE**

JCheckBox       **right**            selected                            **TRUE**  <- wrong?

Comment: That may be because from a UI standpoint, that's not standard practice.  Just curious, why do you want to support right click on those types of buttons?

Comment: This software is actually used by a custom trackball on a medical device that has left, right and center buttons located around it.  They all must work with the UI they control.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Why don't you issue a `doClick()` from your custom mouse handler?